# DialogBox positioning. Adding Class ?

Tags: jquery

Might be a noobie question ... but I didnt find the solution .

I have a dialogBox ...

```
 $("#dialogId").dialog({ position: ['top', 80] });
```

Any chance I can put the position in a class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to jQuery UI [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-dialogClass), you can use the `dialogClass` option:

```
$("#dialogId" ).dialog({ dialogClass: "myClass" });
```

And in your `myClass` specify the position..

```
.myClass { top: 80px }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It doesn't recognize my CSS method. Once I get that working I will accept your answer

Comment: I see, it might be more complicated with positioning.. The class is applied correctly, but the position is being overridden: http://jsfiddle.net/uS8AW/ The position option of dialog seem to be the best way how to deal with it.. You might extract the position from css with jquery and pass it.

Comment: I had to use !important .. I dont really like using it ... but , for this it got the job done

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dialogId").addClass("className");
```

And in this className set position you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be `.my_positioned_dialog { position:absolute; top:80px; }`